# Autocomplete field based on query string using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script, `test.php` using the following HTML & jQuery.

Basically if the user loads this script, I'd like to populate the input field with a random string.

*However*, if the user visits `test.php?id=` type of URL, I don't want to populate this field.

**How am I able to do this with my existing code?**

---

Currently when I run the code below, it gives me this error:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: key is not defined at test.php:28`

```
<input id="input_1_8" name="input_1_8" value="">

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

function makeid()
{
    var text = "";
    var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

    for( var i=0; i < 5; i++ )
        text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

    return text;
}


var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
var keys = urlParams.keys();
for (key of keys) {}
setTimeout(function() {
    if (null === key) { // here is where I get my error!!
    } else {
        $('#input_1_8').val(makeid());
    }
}, 3000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following simple js code to do what you want if query string exists or not.

```
if(document.location.search.length) {
   //query string exists - do something 
}
else
{
   //query string does not exist - do something
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. Please mark the answer as correct as well. Happy coding. :)

Comment: Wil do - you were so fast I'm having to wait 2 more minutes before green tick ;-) ;-) Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

You are referencing "key" outside of the for loop in which it is initialized. Also, your for loop is not initialized properly. Are you looking for a specific key within the loop? If so, I would then set an outside variable to the key value so you can reference inside the timeout..

```js
function makeid() {
  var text = "";
  var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

  return text;
}


var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
var keysURL = urlParams.keys();
var keyVal = null;
for (var keyParam in keysURL) {
  // Whatever conditional here..
  if (true === true) {
    keyVal = keyParam;
    break;
  }
}
setTimeout(function() {
  if (null === keyVal) { // here is where I get my error!!

  } else {
    $('#input_1_8').val(makeid());
  }
}, 3000);
```

```html
<input id="input_1_8" name="input_1_8" value="">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js" integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Many thanks for clarifying this - it's great to understand where I went wrong :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code logic works fine, but 
You did not declare the key variable
You may type

```
var key;
```

or

```
for (var key in keys) {}
```